# Angular ng-class not working but regular class attribute works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this view template that is a child to another view. 
The parent view of this view is a child to the `index.html` where I am importing my `angular` and `ui-router` javascript.
i.e `index.html > other view > view below`
 When I try to change the `class = "bubble me"`  below - which works fine ,to `ng-class = "bubble me"` my css is not loaded. Am I missing something? The issue is isolated to this view only.

```
<div class="top"><span>To: <span class="name">{{chat.name}}</span></span></div>
<div class="chat">
    <div class="conversation-wrapper">

         <div class="conversation-start">
            <span>Today, 6:48 AM</span>
         </div>
         <div class="bubble me" ng-repeat = "message in sent_received">
      {{message.msg}}
          </div>
<div class="write">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="write-link attach"></a>
    <input ng-model = "input.message" type="text" />
    <a href="javascript:;" class="write-link smiley"></a>
    <a ng-click= "sendMsg()" class="write-link send"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you need `ng-class` for a hard coded string that isn't conditional on anything in the first place? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @charlietfl is correct. Is `bubble` an object that can have different values?

Comment: does ng-class work only for conditional classes? I would like to combine my regular hard coded classes with the conditional ones so I dont have both a class attribute and an ng-class attribute in my tags..is there no way of doing this? - in the code above the `bubble` is not dynamic. I would like to make the `me` class only dynamic

Comment: If you want to hard code the class names into `ng-class`, use single quotes. In your case it must be `ng-class="'bubble me'"`

Comment: Not sure why you want to combine them either. Easier knowing what the defaults are by looking at the class attribute. Also adds additional watches needlessly to the view

Comment: @charlietfl so its better to have both a class attribute and a ng-class for the dynamic classes?

Comment: @gilango your solution worked for me..

Comment: Yes...if you don't understand what the impact of adding watches are and how angular digests work don't add needless directives. There is a performance penalty and the browser will render `class` without needing script to compile it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does ng-class work only for conditional classes? I would like to
>   combine my regular hard coded classes with the conditional ones so I
>   dont have both a class attribute and an ng-class attribute in my
>   tags..is there no way of doing this? - in the code above the bubble is
>   not dynamic. I would like to make the me class only dynamic

This might work for your case.

```
ng-class="value=='true'?'bubble me':'bubble'"
```